# I have Elementary OS and windows 8.1 installed but want to remove Elementary OS and install Ubuntu. How can I do that?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8, elementary

I have Elementary OS installed along with windows 8.1. I want to uninstall Elementary OS and install Ubuntu. How can I do that? I searched Google for any relevant article or link but couldn't help myself. Please guide me through the whole procedure.

Comment: Just boot the USB live media in the same mode (UEFI or Lagacy) the other OSes were installed. Then you have two options: 1. Use something else and select for use the exact same partitions used by Elementary or 2. Use something else, remove all Elementary partitions and create new ones. The installer should proceed as usual and, at the end, update Grub accordingly.

Comment: I don't know which mode other operating systems are installed. How can I know abouth their modes?

Comment: If your Windows 8.1 is factory installed and your eOS dual boots without requiring changes to UEFI/BIOS then both are correctly installed in UEFI mode.

Comment: Install Ubuntu using manual partitioning (see the linked question) and remove, or reformat the partitions of Elementary OS in the process.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple.  Boot to the Ubuntu LiveISO and choose the **Do Something Else** option.

Follow the GUI prompts and pick the partition with the OS you want to remove the install partition.

When you pick the partition, you'll have the option of reformating the partition.  Of course reformating the partition will remove all the files from your previous OS.  If you choose not to reformat the drive, the installer will remove the system directories and replace them with Ubuntu.

If you choose not to format, your `/home` folder will be preserved.

If you are trying to preserve your home folder, you might consider renaming that folder before the install.  Some of the configurations files in the `Elementry OS` might conflict with some of the options in the Ubuntu configuration.

You can later copy your documents to the new `home` folder created.